# Scala Syntax Clarification <-

Tags: scala, syntax

Please explain it in simple terms. I'm a beginner in Scala.

What does <- syntax mean in spark? For example:

```
var mylist = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6)

mylist: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> for(i<- mylist) {
     println(i)
}

1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<- is a scala operator rather than that of spark. It is used to traverse a collection. Think of it as an iterator. Its commonly called as for comprehension. In your example it will fetch the values of mylist one by one in each iteration.

more here:
https://alvinalexander.com/scala/iterating-scala-lists-foreach-for-comprehension